# Changing all links on page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I want to change all links on page, it works with links that have no class, but it won't work with links that have class.

This is the code I am using:

```
window.onload = function() {
       /* onload code */

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "http://www.example.com/?redirect=" + anchors[i].href
}
}
```

It works for links such as:

```
<a id="box-left" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
```

But doesn't work for this:

```
<a class="links" href="redirect.php?link=125411" onclick="launch();" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Try to use first anchors[i].removeAttribute("href"); and then set it.
And instead of window.onload use document.onload can be triggered.
And would be better if you provide your code into jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 2):

I think that the correct function should be :

```
window.onload = function() {
   /* onload code */

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "http://www.mysite.com/?redirect=" + anchors[i].href
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry there was a typo and yes I am using "a" instead of "class" but it still doesn't change links that use class.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

instead of

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("class");
```

BTW I recommend you to use jquery to select dom elements.

Comment: Hello, sorry there was a typo and yes I am using "a" instead of "class" but it still doesn't change links that use class.

Comment: find my suggestion in next answer

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code as it is posted and it worked for me.
I put the javascript in a  tag and the links in the body.
Maybe there is something else on the page interfering.

Comment: Could it be that the page I want to change links on is in iframe?

Comment: I think the CSS can mix somthing as I've written above. JS looks OK for me too

Comment: I'm not sure about the iFrame.  You can always check if the JavaScript gets hit by putting an alert() at the start of the function and check if it completes all the way through with another alert at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some strange CSS whick mix something with this link with this class="links" attribute? You can also try add class to both kind of links and select by class.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic_links");

<a id="box-left" class="dynamic_links" href="http://www.google.com"></a> 

<a class="links dynamic_links" href="redirect.php?link=125411" onclick="launch();" target="_blank"></a>
```

Let me know what about this ok ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, its as simple as this:

```
$('a').attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```