# How to append a random number (or time in milliseconds) to all links on a page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, reload

I have a static HTML page at the address `https://MyPage/index.html`

The page contains several images, which are located at
`https://MyPage/MyImages`

The images are linked in the HTML source code like this:

`…<span><img  width=x height=y src="MyImages/imageXYZ.png"</span>…`

When a button is clicked or, even better, when the page is loaded, all image links should be rewritten by appending a random number or, for example, the current time in milliseconds, so that the links look like this afterwards:

`…<span><img  width=x height=y src="MyImages/imageXYZ.png?1587624427"</span>…`

I believe that possible starting points can be found here:

[Changing all links on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884910/changing-all-links-on-page)

[How to Change All Links with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291272/how-to-change-all-links-with-javascript)

[How can I change every link on a page to something new?](https://lab.artlung.com/change-all-links/)

Starting from there, how can I add to the examples given such that (instead of a constant redirect) a random number or the time in milliseconds is appended to all image links?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href]").forEach(....)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const time_to_img = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(e => {
    const dateStr = Date.now();
    const date = new Date(dateStr);
    e.src = e.src + '?' + date.getTime();
  })
}
window.addEventListener('load', time_to_img);
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200" alt="">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/7/300/200" alt="">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/300/200" alt="">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/300/200" alt="">
```

in the loop you have calculation of time in millisecond which is added to the src of each image after ?

now if you want different number for each image, you'll have to add something (random number?). Here for 4 images everything is done in same millisecond

Comment: Thank you -- that totally worked! 
(I assigned it to a button)

Where would I need to put the script in the HTML source so that it runs every time (before) the page loads?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13291508/1388921

Comment: I changed the snippet for you with the window load

Comment: Dang, can't seem to post code in a comment. Please see below ↓

Answer (score 0):

I had done this in the meantime:

```html
<body onload="CacheBuster()";>

<script>
function CacheBuster() {
    document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(e => {
      const dateStr = Date.now();
      const date = new Date(dateStr);
      e.src = e.src + '?' + date.getTime();
    })
    }
</script>
```

Is that any good? It seems to work perfectly!

Comment: That's ok. I wouldn't recommend to use body onload. I always prefer for this king of function to have them "almost" independent. Declared in a const, and has it's own window load listener. You can put it where you want. Anyway if you don't need to have different numbers (millisecond here), perhaps better to declare a variable before the for Each with date calculation.

Comment: Thank you. It's only a couple dozen links, so I left it as is. It works almost magically, the browser even swaps out any old (cached) images without having to reload the page, for example when running the script manually from a button.